# Display preview of image in semi-automatic classification plugin in QGIS does not load in layers

Tags: qgis, error, satellite, download

I have being trying to load Landsat or Sentinel-2 satellite images into the map layers panel within QGIS v26.3 with the latest version of the semi-automatic classification plugin.

The screen just flashes when I click the blue download button in the download products screen.  Nothing gets loaded into the map layers panel.  This plug-in has a 5 star rating by QGIS users.  I give it a 1* rating based on the simplest of tasks.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I think its to do with the preview in Layers option which doesnt work.  If you untick the box that says 'only if preview in Layers' it will download the files but be careful because if your search results are many then it will download them ALL and take ages.